# Two matrices with approximately the same spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two diagnolizable square block Toeplitz matrices with the same size but different generating symbols, and their spectra are approximately the same, that is $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)+O(L^{-1})$ where $L$ is the size of the two matrices. A typical case is that when set $L=100$ only $4$ eigenvalues among all differ slightly, and all other eigenvalues are the same.

I want to know if there is a method to compute a similarity transformation or at least an 'approximate similarity transformation' to connect $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Same notation for matrices and integers is confusing

Comment: @renn Diagonalize both $A$ and $B$ separately, arranging the eigenvalues so that the approximately equal values occupy corresponding diagonal entries. If the matrices $PAP^{-1}$ and $QBQ^{-1}$ are (diagonal and) approximately equal, then it follows that the matrices $(Q^{-1}P)A(Q^{-1}P)^{-1}$ and $B$ are approximately equal.

Comment: More concretely, it should be possible to bound $\|(Q^{-1}P)A(Q^{-1}P)^{-1} - B\|$ in terms of $\|PAP^{-1} - QBQ^{-1}\|$ (which corresponds to the extent of difference between the eigenvalues) and the condition number $\kappa(Q)$.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be productive to try to minimize $\|UA - BU\|$ subject to the constraint that $U$ is invertible. The Frobenius norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ would make minimizing $\|UA - BU\|_F$ on its own a linear least-squares problem, but the invertibility constraint may pose a challenge. Perhaps you could find an optimization approach that allows you to penalize based on the condition number of $U$.